# highcharts-react-native series is not hidding when click on legend

Tags: react-native, highcharts, highcharts-react-native

I'm trying to achieve the same thing as highchart web version: when I click on the legend "Series 1" -> the series will be disappear from the chart. https://jsfiddle.net/fq9t5e7w/

But on highcharts-react-native, the behavior is different, when I click on the legend, the series is "blur" instead of "hidding"

Before click:

[image]

After click:

[image]

I also try with the plot option

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: () => {
            console.log('series point click this.visible');
            let series = this.series.chart.series;
            const seriesIndex = this.series.index;
            for (let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
              if (series[i].index !== seriesIndex) {
                series[i].visible ? series[i].hide() : series[i].show();
              }
            }
            return false;
          },
        },
      },
      events: {
        legendItemClick: () => {
          console.log('legendItemClick this.visible');
```

But the method is not executed when I click on series legend.

What should I do to make this work? Thank for your help.

Comment: I've tested this library in expo managed project and was unable to recreate this situation. It'll be if you provide more working code. An expo snack may be better.

Comment: Here is the source code https://github.com/mrpmohiburrahman/Highcharts_demo

Comment: Here is the recording of the live app https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aYDPoC-NJy6weVWHX5CdjjhP4uDa7lbU/view?usp=sharing